# On the nature of Sri Krishna

Tags: puranas, krishna, nature, vaishnav

If sri Krishna is beyond material existence then how or why did he leave behind his body after his death is there a story behind this ?

Comment: Everyone is beyond material existence. You are not flesh and bones, but eternal soul beyond material existence, like Krishna and everyone has to leave soil they gathered back to the place.

Answer (score 0):

God Krishna is called MAAYAAVI. How can human believe God may leave his body on Earth? NEVER. To hide secrets of reunion to JAGATHCHAKRAM(the constellation of universe) by GOD, the soul energy transformation had taken place through another kingly human form thereby making humans believe human form has death certainly.
"PARAMAATMA PARAMAANU ROOPA".
Example: Laser is invisible but it chars an object within seconds. The laser size is 100 times less than artillery beiring guns used in war.